# Access VBA Dynamic Excel Import

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to dynamically import an Excel Spreadsheet into Access. The problem is, i need to import a specific sheet (this part sorted out), but I'm having problems importing a sheet whose name changes month to month.

Code example:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "MonthSales", FileName, 1, "Sales_Month!"
```

On the `"Sales_Month!"` is where i need it to be dynamic. I can import it directly if the sheet has always the same name. So my question is, can i import it with some sort of wildcard?

For example: `"Sales_*!"`

Note: This Excel Workbook has several worksheets.

Comment: In Excel VBA, you could loop through `Worksheets` and check if the current sheet's name is `Like "Sales_*!"`. Something equivalent is presumably doable in Access VBA.

Comment: I totally agree with @Jean-FrançoisCorbett and I upvoted his/her comment. Loop trough all sheets checking all names until you find the one you want and then activate it. Then, once activated, you could use `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "MonthSales", FileName, 1, ActiveSheet.Name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be simple a solution, looking for Excel Sheet names in a for cycle with `Left` operator:

```
Dim xls As New Excel.Application, sht As String, Wkb As Workbook, Wksh As Worksheet
Set Wkb = xls.Workbooks.Open(FileName)

For Each Wksh In Wkb.Worksheets
  if left(Wksh.Name, 6) = "Sales_" then
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "MonthSales", FileName, 1, Wksh.Name
      Exit For
  end if
Next Wksh

Wkb.Close
xls.Quit
Set Wkb = Nothing
Set xls = Nothing
Exit Sub
```

Comment: For this code to work, I think user must need to add a reference to Microsoft Excel Objects Library, because it is executing it from Access. Also ¿no binding? ¿is not necessary first to do a `Set xls = New Excel.Application` before doing `Set Wkb = xls.Workbooks.Open(FileName)`?